# Parse.User.Login is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

I'm teaching myself a bit of Javascript & Parse.com.  I'm following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vB5lo9bx57s&list=PLoN_ejT35AEhbFswEKW36LxzyXJs7xCWS&index=6

Here is the code.  The issue is that I cannot log in.  When I try, I get the following returned message in the console:

> TypeError: Parse.User.LogIn is not a function

I'm a bit lost, as it clearly is a function that works both on the video & on other tutorials.

```
<h1>Log In!</h1>

<form id="login">
  <p><input id="login-name" type="text"></p>
  <p><input id="login-password" type="password"></p>
  <p><input id="login-submit" type="submit"></p>
</form>

<h1>Sign Up!</h1>
<form id="signup">
  <p><input id="signup-name" type="text"></p>
  <p><input id="signup-password" type="password"></p>
  <p><input id="signup-submit" type="submit"></p>
</form>

<h1>You're ready to use Parse!</h1>

<form id="post-form">
  <p><input id="post-title" type="text"></p>
  <p><textarea id="post-content"></textarea></p>
  <p><input type="radio" name="post-select" value="0" checked>Not Selected
  <br><input type="radio" name="post-select" value="1">One
  <br><input type="radio" name="post-select" value="2">Two
  <br><input type="radio" name="post-select" value="3">Three
  <br><input type="radio" name="post-select" value="4">Four
  </p>
  <p><input id="post-submit" type="submit"></p>
</form>

<ul id="list-posts">
    <!--
      <li>
          <h3></h3>
          <p></p>
      </li>
     -->
</ul>
```

```
Parse.initialize("abc", "123");

    var Post = Parse.Object.extend("Post");

    $("#login").submit(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();

        var name = $("#login-name").val();
        var pass = $("#login-password").val();

      Parse.User.LogIn(name, pass, {
        success: function(user){
          console.log("Log In Success!");
        }, error: function(user, error){
          console.log("Log In Error:"+error.message);
        }
      });
    });

    $("#signup").submit(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();

      var name = $("#signup-name").val();
      var pass = $("#signup-password").val();

      var user = new Parse.User();
      user.set("username",name);
      user.set("password",pass);

      user.signUp(null, {
        success: function(){
          //
        }, error: function(user, error){
          console.log("signup error:"+error.message);
        }
      });
    });

    function getPosts() {
      var query = new Parse.Query(Post);
      query.find({
        success: function(results) {
          var output = "";
          for (var i in results) {
            var title = results[i].get("title");
            var content = results[i].get("content");
            var pselect = results[i].get("pselect");

            output += "<li>";
            output += "<h3>"+title+"</h3>";
            output += "<p>"+content+"</p>";
            output += "<p>"+pselect+"</p>";
            output += "</li>";
          }
          $("#list-posts").html(output);
        }, error: function(){
          console.log("Query Error:"+error.message);
      }
      });
    }

    getPosts ();

    $("#post-form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var title = $("#post-title").val();
    var content = $("#post-content").val();
    var pselect = $(":input[name=post-select]:checked").val();

    var newPost = new Post();
    newPost.set("title", title);
    newPost.set("content", content);
    newPost.set("pselect", pselect);

    newPost.save({
        success: function(){
          getPosts ();
      },
        error: function(error){
        console.log("Error:"+error.message);
      }
     });
});
```

Comment: can you show your html headers(js sources)?

Comment: Sure: `  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>My Parse App</title>
  <meta name="description" content="My Parse App">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-latest.js"></script>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript is a case sensitive language. You need to use

Parse.User.logIn

instead of Parse.User.LogIn that you have in code that you provided.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Knew it would be something daft!